# How to programmatically or dynamically add ajax listener to JSF 2 component?

Tags: ajax, dynamic, jsf-2, listeners

How to programmatically or dynamically add ajax listener to JSF 2 component?
I tried:

```
  ...
  FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  AjaxBehavior dragStart = (AjaxBehavior)facesContext.getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
  dragStart.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new DragEnterListener());
  dragStart.setTransient(true);
  component.addClientBehavior("dragstart", dragStart);
  ...

  public class DragEnterListener implements AjaxBehaviorListener {

    @Override
    public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
      System.out.println("AjaxListener CALLED!!! ");
    }
  }
```

But thid doesn't work. In page I've got this JS exception:

```
serverError: class java.lang.IllegalStateException  
cz.boza.formcreator.FormModel$DragEnterListener
```

I found this example in RichFaces:
http://community.jboss.org/message/611571

But in plain JSF 2 in AjaxBehavior class there is no

```
addAjaxBehaviorListener(MethodExpression methodExpression)
```

there is only

```
addAjaxBehaviorListener(ValueExpression valueExpression)
```

I'm trying to solve this for many days.
Please help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Otherwise we have no idea of the call path which ultimately caused the
 exception. This information is all in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I made more research and found that if the `component` in which I wan't to add ajax listener is also added dynamically (from java - like `parant.getChildren().add(component)`) into the page, everything works fine.

But if `component` in which I wan't to add ajax listener is is added statically (in jsp - like `<h:panelGroup binding="#{bean.component}">`) into the page, aforementioned weird exception is thrown:

```
serverError: class java.lang.IllegalStateException
cz.boza.formcreator.FormModel$DragEnterListener
```

I will try to ask this question in JSF forum. May be it's a bug in Mojara.